# How to boot from Iso file with grub and Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: boot, grub2, iso

I know my question is commented on a lot. But I read so many posts and none could really clarify my problem. But it may also be that I did not understand the topic correctly.

On my Systems exists 4 SSD

```
/dev/nvme0n1
    ...
    /dev/nvme0n1p5 reserved for ISO Files (UUID = 2E644A863FF78FC1)
    ...
    /dev/nvme0n1p8 Ubuntu 22.04 (UUID = 84a89553-b126-40fd-9eed-36cca355fce8)

/dev/sda » data disk
/dev/sdb » data disk
/dev/sdc » data disk
```

In Grub i have this code for loading my iso file

```
insmod ntfs
GRUB_DEVICE_UUID=2E644A863FF78FC1
set isofile="clonezilla-live-2022-06-20-jammy-x64.iso"
loopback loop $isofile
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noeject noprompt splash --
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
```

As soon the ISO file was selected at boot time, I get the Error

```
Invalid file name clonezilla-live-2022-06-20-jammy-x64.iso
No Server specific
You need to load the kernel first
```

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Maybe the examples for Ubuntu at [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot#Manually_editing_the_GRUB_files) can help you modify your menuentry until it works.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a copy of the piece of my grub.cfg you need:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

menuentry "Peppermint-10" {
set isofile="/Peppermint-10-20191210-amd64.iso"
loopback loop (/dev/nvme0np7)$isofile
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinux boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/Peppermint-10-20191210-amd64.iso noprompt noeject quit splash
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
```

Replace menuentry with yours.
Replace partitionnumber with yours.
Replace the name of the .iso with the exact name of your .iso. 
The file has to placed in the root of the partition ( e.g. nvme0np3/blah blah.iso ).

Comment: Thank you for your rich information.
I haven't had much time in the past few days, but I was able to try everything today.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not all tips worked immediately.
Casper only works if this folder and its files are also on the ISO. As a beginner, you quickly lose sight of this.
The same applies to LIVE and EFI.

In order to get the right settings for hd and gpt, it makes more sense to reboot the system. Open the input prompt in Grub and run a simple 'ls'.

I haven't managed Windows itself yet, but I don't think that's possible either. Since the Windows setup needs access to files even after a restart. In this scenario, grub would not premount an ISO
and Windows Setup loses its ability to continue installing.

For example, starting a Kubuntu 22 ISO.
However, I was able to use this procedure successfully:

```
set iso="/kubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso"
insmod ext2
insmod loopback
insmod iso9660
loopback loop (hd3,gpt5)$iso
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz  file=(loop)/preseed/kubuntu.seed noprompt boot=casper persistent iso-scan/filename=$iso quiet splash --
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
```

GParted and Clonezilla can boot with following commands:

```
set iso="/gparted-live-1.4.0-5-amd64.iso"
loopback loop (hd3,gpt5)$iso
linuxefi (loop)/live/vmlinuz boot=live components config findiso=$iso ip=frommedia toram=filesystem.squashfs union=overlay
initrdefi (loop)/live/initrd.img
```

Another way to boot any ISO would be to install Ventoy on a hard drive. Although it was originally designed for mobile data carriers, it can also be integrated for local HDD/SSD drives.

Comment: Glad you got this working.