# Grub2 | Can not locate iso file

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, persistence

I am trying to add an Ubuntu 20.04.4 ISO to Grub2 and it says it can not find the ISO file.
I am currently running Debian 11 32bit- my computer is a bit of a weird one, a 32bit BIOS but the CPU supports 64bit OS's (Thanks Baytrail CPU's for making it complicated). Also I did update the GrubV1 that Debian 11 32bit comes with to GrubV2.

I currently have my file saved to `/home/username/Downloads/ubuntu_20.04.4` (I shorthanded the filename - it is 64bit).

This is my `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` menu entry

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu Live Persistent'  {
   set isofile="/home/username/Downloads/ubuntu_20.04.4.iso"
   loopback loop (hd0,1)$isofile
   linux  (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile persistent noprompt noeject
   initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

I pieced that together from a few Ubuntu forum posts on making a live persistent menu entry.

I double checked and I believe my mmcblk1p1 drive is listed as hd0,1 - and also that the error I was getting before is no longer there with regards to a non-existent hdX,Y. Also that my mmcblk1p1 is the first partition listed in gparted that has my `/boot/efi/`

I am not sure what else to do to get it to boot with Grub2. I just need a few programs that do not have 32 bit support, so I am trying to make it a live persistent OS for when I need those certain programs. If you have any idea what is wrong or what needs changed, please let me know. I've been at this for a few weeks now and it's driving me nuts.

If you need it, here is my computer: `Asus T200TA-C2-BL`

Please let me know if I can give you any more information, I am somewhat new to Linux and the information I gathered is still new to me.

Edit: here are my errors in GrubV2

```
error: file '/home/username/Downloads/ubuntu_20.04.4.iso' not found 
error: no server is specified 
error: you need to load the kernel first
```

Edit#2, I fixed my capitalization of `isofile` as someone pointed out, still did not fix it.

Comment: Capitalization is critical, isofile is not the same as isoFile

Comment: What is the *exact* text of the error message?

Comment: Edited and added to the post for easier reading

Comment: 1. You may need `rmmod tpm` according to [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot#Menuentry_Example); 2. Are you using ***your*** username (not literally 'username')? Please check that the file is actually where you tell grub to find it; 3. Are you sure that there should be `initrd.lz`? Ubuntu uses 'only' `initrd` nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Place the .iso in the `/` (root) partition. 
add this to your `grub.cfg` :

```
menuentry "Ubuntu" {
insmod ext2
set isofile="/ubuntu-20.04.4.0_.iso"
loopback loop (hd0,7)$isofile
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject quiet splash toram
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
}
```

Do this as root and save the file. Make sure the name of the .iso is the same. Mind that I did not try to add the `persistent` part. You can try and add that parameter. And of course you can leave out the `quiet splash` and the `toram` parameters.
Replace the '7' in `hd0,7` with the number your partition has.

Comment: I know this works from another answer from you. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423874/how-to-boot-from-iso-file-with-grub-and-ubuntu-22-04/1423909?r=SearchResults&s=11%7C4.8295#1423909. I used it for a Peppermint.iso.

Answer (score 0):

I never could make a iso booting over grub in debian when the iso file was in my $HOME.

I put my iso in a folder under /boot.
please adapt it to your situation (like isoname a.s.o).

```
# ubuntu-20.10 (gorilla) iso integrieren.

#!/bin/sh -e
export ISOFILE="/boot/ubuntu-gorilla/ubuntu-20.10-desktop-amd64.iso"
echo "Found ubuntu-20.10.iso" >&2

cat << EOF
menuentry "ubuntu-20.10" {
    load_video
    insmod loopback
    insmod iso9660
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    insmod ntfs
    insmod btrfs
    search -n -f --set=root ${ISOFILE}
    loopback loop ${ISOFILE}
    echo 'Loading Linux linux ...'
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=${ISOFILE} noprompt noeject setxkbmap=de
    echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
    }
EOF
exit 0
```

[image: gorilla isoboot]